# Why does 1 == &2 not compile?

Tags: rust

I tried to compile the following code to understand the behavior of comparison operators applied to references:

```
fn main() {
    &1 == &2;              // OK
    &&1 == &&2;            // OK
    &1 == &mut 2;          // OK
    &mut(&1) == &(&mut 2); // OK
    1 == &2;               // Compilation Error
    &1 == &&2;             // Compilation Error
}
```

According to this result, for type `T` implementing `PartialEq`, it seems that

1. References of `T`s, references of references of `T`s, ... are comparable.
2. Shared and mutable references can be mixed.
3. The amount of references for both sides of `==` must be the same.

Where do these rules come from? Rule 1 and 2 can be derived from [the semantics of comparison operators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#comparison-operators) and deref coercion. Consider `&1 == &mut 2`:

1. The expression is interpreted as `PartialEq::eq(&&1, &(&mut 2))` by the compiler.
2. The first argument `&&1` turns into `&1` by deref coercion because [`&T` implements `Deref<Target = T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#implementors).
3. The second argument `&(&mut 2)` turns into `&2` by deref coercion because [`&mut T` implements `Deref<Target = T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#implementors).
4. Now the types of both arguments match the signature of `PartialEq::eq` implemented by `i32`. So `PartialEq::<i32>::eq(&1, &2)` is evaluated.

However, I don't understand where Rule 3 comes from. I think `PartialEq::eq(&1, &&2)` is coerced to `PartialEq::eq(&1, &2)` because deref coercion is applied to the both arguments independently.

What is the rationale of Rule 3? Please show documented semantics of Rust or the appropriate code in the compiler?

Comment: What's even more curious is that a "handmade" `PartialEq` implementation *actually works* with such cases: [playground](http://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=574fdb76c93288b45770691c8630e8ef&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015).

Answer (score 2):

It seems like deref coercion isn't taking place when using the operators (I am not sure why this is), however borrows may still be used due to an implementation of `PartialEq`.

From the Rust documentation of [`PartialEq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html) the following implementation can be seen:

```
impl<'a, 'b, A, B> PartialEq<&'b B> for &'a A 
where
    A: PartialEq<B> + ?Sized,
    B: ?Sized,
```

This states there is an implementation for a borrow of type `B` and a borrow for type `A` if there exists an implementation of `PartialEq` for type `A` and `B`.

Given this definition, `&i32 == &i32`  can be used because `i32` implements `PartialEq` and given the above impl this dictates `PartialEq` is implemented for borrows of `i32`s. This then leads to the recursive case that `&&i32 == &&i32` works because `PartialEq` is implemented for `&i32` so given the above impl `PartialEq` is also implemented for `&&i32`.

Because of the definition of this implementation the number of borrows on both sides must be the same.

Comment: *It seems like deref coercion isn't taking place when using the operators* — it's unclear to me what you are basing this statement on.

Comment: I am basing this on the premise that if deref coercion was taking place, the examples in the question would all be working. When I get a chance I will try to find more solid evidence of this.

Comment: Deref coercion always converts to a reference (&T -> &U, &&T -> &U, &&&T -> &U), etc. I don't see how it would come into play here.